# How to query a hibernate set of strings?

Tags: hibernate, associations, grails-orm, scalar

I'm using Gorm to attempt to query over an association that is represented as a Set. I want to know if one or the other of two values is contained in the association. My problem is I don't know how to represent this since its not a separate object but rather a simple string. I've tried variations on the following (obviously incorrect):

```
def c = CobraUser.createCriteria();
def results = c.listDistinct {
    children {
      or {
        eq("children", "stringA")
        eq("children", "stringB")
      }
   }
}
```

Not sure how to write the eq() part, or if I can use an "in" somehow...

Answer (score 0):

I ended with HQL which I don't really care for:

from User user JOIN user.children uc WHERE uc in ('xyz','abc')